# I have problem with add image using javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to add an image to a website using a javascript array. I found a code and then I tried to change it. But i can't get it to work. My code does not display the image on the site.

**Code I found:**

```
const imageOut = document.querySelector('.image-out');
for (let key in images) {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('data-key', key);
    img.src = 'images/' + key + '.png';
    imageOut.append(img);
}
```

html tag: `<div class="image-out"></div>`
Array:

```
const images = {"JD-03-128" :{},"JD-05-128": {},"JD-07-128": {},"JD-11-128": {},"JD-12-128": {},"JD-13-128": {},"JD-15-128": {}};
```

My code:

```
var imageOut = document.querySelector(".image-out");
for (let key in a) {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('data-key', key);
    img.src = 'image/'+key+'.jpg';
    imageOut.append(img);
}
```

html tag: `<div class="image-out"></div>`
Array:

```
const a = {"a":{},"b":{},"c":{},"d":{},"e":{},"f":{},"g":{}};
```

image my code: jpg, name absolutely match, name folder absolutely match with folder in my code.
where is my problem ?

Comment: I see no arrays in this post. Arrays looks like `const images = ["JD03", "JD05"]` for example

Comment: Your code looks fine and it is creating the images properly. Kindly check the file path properly. I created a jsfiddle for you to have a look. https://jsfiddle.net/v4Lkoshm/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append (add) multiple images to an HTML document using an array, then you can do something like below.

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')

const array = [
  'https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/300'
]

array.forEach((src) => {
  const imageElement = document.createElement('img')
  imageElement.src = src
  rootElement.appendChild(imageElement)
})
```

```css
img{margin:5px}
```

```html
<div id='root'></div>
```

### Explanation

So basically I'm creating an `<img src='' />` element for every item in the array. The items in the array are the url (src) of the images. Those are added as an attribute to the `imageElement` like so `imageElement.src = src` and finally they are appended as a child of `rootElement`